# UIView Animations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

Why doesn't this code do anything?

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"View Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn forView:self.view cache:YES];

[self.view removeFromSuperview];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Also, where can I see all the list of possible arguments for beginAnimations:?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set the animation transition on the view containing the change, e.g..

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                       forView:self.view.superview cache:YES];
```

Also, the transition should be a constant of type [UIViewAnimationTransition](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationTransition).

The `+beginAnimations:context:` method can take any string as its 1st argument, and any pointer as its 2nd argument.

Comment: What is the purpose of giving an arbitrary string to beginAnimations?

Comment: @awake: Give an identifier to the animation, in case you have a `+setAnimationWillStartSelector:` etc.

Comment: All I had to do was add superview and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use **QuartzCore.framework** With these animations.

```
-(void)viewSlideInFromRightToLeft:(UIView *)views
{
    CATransition *transition = nil;
    transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;//kAnimationDuration
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromRight;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [views.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}

-(void)viewSlideInFromLeftToRight:(UIView *)views
{
    CATransition *transition = nil;
    transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;//kAnimationDuration
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromLeft;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [views.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}

-(void)viewSlideInFromTopToBottom:(UIView *)views
{
    CATransition *transition = nil;
    transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;//kAnimationDuration
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromBottom ;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [views.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}

-(void)viewSlideInFromBottomToTop:(UIView *)views
{
    CATransition *transition = nil;
    transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.5;//kAnimationDuration
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype =kCATransitionFromTop ;
    transition.delegate = self;
    [views.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
}
```

For *AnimationType* you can use following options: 
`kCATransitionMoveIn`, 
`kCATransitionPush`, 
`kCATransitionReveal`, 
`kCATransitionFade`.

For *AnimationSubType* you can use following options: 
`kCATransitionFromLeft`, 
`kCATransitionFromRight`, 
`kCATransitionFromTop`, 
`kCATransitionFromBottom`.